# How do you use an object reference as a key in a C# dictionary when the class implements Equals and GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

If you have a class that implements `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, can you force a dictionary using that class as a key to compare based on the object's reference rather than generating a hash or comparing using `Equals`?

For example, if I have a collection of global, unchanging `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in my resources, Can I use them as keys in a dictionary cheaply by having them compare based on what in C++ would be their address? These are pretty big images and I'd hate to have it generate the hash even once to do a key lookup.

I'm just hoping for a more optimal way to use these objects as keys given their references and contents will never change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a `Dictionary` with a custom `IEqualityComparer`, which calls into `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode` and uses `object.ReferenceEquals` for equality comparison:

```
class IdentityEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class {
    public bool Equals(T v1, T v2) {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(v1, v2);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T v) {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(v);
    }
}
```

Now you can make a dictionary like this:

```
var identityDict = new Dictionary<MyKey,MyVal>(
    new IdentityEqualityComparer<MyKey>();
);
```

Comment: That worked great. Unfortunately, it seems `Properties.Resources` properties are not global and change every time you get them. So much for that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to look into is a database. Visual Studio comes with the ability to create SQL databases. From there, you can map one value to another. For example: You can have a string of randomly generated numbers map to the filepath of the image. I'm not very familiar with System.Drawing, so I don't know if you could create a database of programatically generated images.